# The Participle in Participle Phrases, is an adjective, an noun or a verb?

Tags: grammar

For example, I know a pond teeming with fish.

The Participle Phrases teeming with fish is an adjective describing pond.
But what about teeming itself?

Comment: "Teeming" is a **verb** and "teeming with fish" is a participial **clause**.

Comment: A participle is part of a verb, but here it is functioning as an adjective, as you say.

Comment: No, @KateBunting:  it's not functioning as an adjective, but as **predicator** in the clause "teeming with fish. Note that adjective is a word class like "big", "green", "pretty" etc. It's not a function.

Answer (score 1):

> *I know a pond teeming with fish.*

"Teeming with fish" is not an adjective. It's a non-finite participial **clause** modifying "pond". Not everything that modifies a noun is an adjective!

Within the participial clause, "teeming" functions as predicator (verb).

Comment: Don't clauses have to have a subject and a predicate?  *Teeming with fish* doesn't have a subject.

Comment: @LawrenceC No: non-finite clauses generally have no _overt_ subject. The clause "teeming with fish" consists of just the predicate verb phrase. The subject is recoverable from the matrix clause, and is clearly "a pond".